# Rails 2: Is it possible to develop a form.select linked to a returning value of an helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller named `store_controller.rb` and method `index` that renders `index.html.erb`, displaying some products. I'm thinking about the chance of placing in this view a form.select (a sort of drop-down menu) with values like (high price items, economic items). I want these values select products by a value returned by an helper method, that in call in view `index.html.erb`.

My question is: Developing this drop-down menu - using, for example, `f.select` - is it possible to link a drop-down menu in Rails to a value returned by an helper method? For example: `<%= f.select :product, :returned_value_by_helper_method [[title, value..]] %>` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `select_tag`, to which you can add whatever options you like (search web for `options_for_select` and `options_for_select_tag`). This will be static, however. If you want dynamic, consider Unobtrusive JavaScript and form observers.

Comment: Thanks sorrow. I will search on the web for select_tag and options. But, if I want to dynamic, Can i both consider RJS?

Comment: One last thing. If I want to display this dropdown menu, with a submit button or something dynamic, can I display the results by partials? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible. One of the great things about Rails (and other good frameworks) is the separation of presentation from the data. So, you can present the data in whatever way you like. If you want the drop-down to react to user selection (without user submitting the form), you need to use form observers (cool stuff) and JavaScript. Rails 3 differs **a lot** from Rails 2 in this matter, be aware of that (new Rails has Unobtrusive JS). Regardless of Rails, the JS code will react to the selection and will call whatever controller/action you specify, in which you can `render :partial`.